# Object is distorted & transparent after joining w/another object

Tags: modeling, objects, transparency

I'm fairly still new to Blender & currently in the learning process. I just cannot figure out how to join these two infuriatingly disobedient objects correctly.

Ultimately I would like to export this as single mesh & use as game content, but in order to do this I need to **merge the two UV maps together so that I can just have one UV map.** I know in order to do this I have to join the objects....

Both models are from SketchFab. They were downloaded separately, and each came as multiple parts instead of one solid object. I had no issues when I joined the respective parts to each model, but then when I try to join both models together, one of the models ends up being distorted/transparent. It happens either way - whether i'm joining the airpods to the case or in vise versa (either object gets distorted depending on which one I join first).

I've read that recalculating the normals can help, but when I try to do this it still gets distorted only to a lesser degree.

I'm hoping there's a solution, but this has been trial & error at it's finest. I might be at a disadvantage since I am not the original creators (both of whom may have used modifiers, etc...) i'm guessing it would've probably been easier if I was able to go back & rework the meshes from scratch. Nonetheless, ANY help would be truly be appreciated as i've been racking my brain & working on & off on this for the last month or so. I'm so ready to wrap this project up, remediable or not. Thank you in advance!

**.blend file was too large to upload on the Blend-Exchange, I uploaded to Google docs instead:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MjIcy06xQdWYny7nLjvQrFBUetBqYFtC/view?usp=sharing

---

**Before join:**

[image]

**After join:**

*(airpods to case)*

[image]

*(case to airpods)*

[image]

**After recalculating normals:**

[image]

Comment: Try resetting the scale on each object and see if that helps. Select each object in turn in Object mode and then CTRL-A and select 'All Transforms'. Then try to join them.

Comment: Thank you for responding! When I select an object in Object mode, I don't get the 'All Transforms' option? [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHNlUoMU8mzLR9x1KRo54ckYb54n0z2b/view?usp=sharing) I probably should've mentioned that i'm using Blender v2.70. Should I upgrade to a different version?

Comment: Ah ok. It's years since I last used (or even saw) Blender 2.70. I looked at your file in 2.91.2 which is the current released version but it really depends on your PC as to whether it will run later versions of Blender. Try ALT-S in Object mode with the object selected which should reset the scale in 2.70. You should be able to see the scale on the properties panel by pressing 'N' and looking under the Transform section near the bottom. The X, Y, and Z scale should be reset to 1.

Comment: Hi John! I've managed to figure out how to reset the scales to 1 via Alt+S. The airpods shrink down, but when I reset the scales on the case, it becomes huge & gets flipped upside-down; then when I try to rotate the case and scale it down to the size of the re-scaled airpods the scales of the case are no longer at 1. I hope that's not too hard to understand, I can screen record & link what i'm talking about if necessary

Comment: All I can say is that the scale resets fine here and I can join the objects without problem in Blender 2.91, **however** trying to UV unwrap the object after doing that takes for ever even on a powerful PC, I suspect mainly because of the terrible mesh that Sketchfab produces! The result is an object with 435000 faces, 893000 edges and 840000 tris which I don't think any game engine would like much! I suspect that you'd be better to model a much simpler version from scratch in Blender to be honest!